# How to setup function in PHP with included file

Tags: php

I've got 3 pages. I have made `include("include/header.php)` with the beggining of the HTML webpage + navigation. When the user was on the contact page than navigation link was underlined `text-decoration: underline;` My question is: How do I make the function, which will automaticly change the class - `.underline` when the user goes to that page? Thanks!

My header.php navigation code

```
<div class="navigation>
<a href="index.php" class="underline">Home<a> <!-- simulating that the user is on this page -->
<a href="about.php">About me</a>
<a href="contact.php">Contact me!</a>
</div>
```

My css code

```
.underline {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Code at index.php and other includingheader.php

`<?php include("include/header.php") ?>`

Comment: Just a tip, you have an error in your HTML.  You're missing a double quote in what should be <div class="navigation">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
function underline($page) {
    if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $page) !== false) {
        echo "underline";
    }
}
?>

<div class="navigation>
<a href="index.php" class="<?php underline('index.php'); ?>">Home<a> <!-- simulating that the user is on this page -->
<a href="about.php" class="<?php underline('about.php'); ?>">About me</a>
<a href="contact.php" class="<?php underline('contact.php'); ?>">Contact me!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: No need to get the entire URI.  Also, you'll have empty class attributes on every anchor that is not the current page.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! This works! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I take a completely different approach to this sort of thing.

First, set up an array of pages for your links, then loop through them, checking if it's the "current" page, and adding the relevant class.

This technique requires less code to output a given link, and is far simpler to add more pages to.

```
<?php
$pages = array(
    'Home'        => 'index.php',
    'About me'    => 'about.php',
    'Contact me!' => contact.php'
    // Now adding pages is easy, just add the relevant parts here
);
?>
<div class="navigation">
<?php 
    // Loop over each page from the array
    foreach($pages AS $title => $page) {
        // Set the class depending on which page is current
        $class = (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $page) !== FALSE) ? 'underline' : '';
        // Output the link
        echo "<a href='{$page}' class='{$class}'>{$title}</a>";
} ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your include/header.php file, use this...

```
function is_current($page){

   $current = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
   if($current == $page){

       return ' class="underline"';

    }

 }

<div class="navigation">
<a href="index.php"<?php echo is_current('index.php'); ?>>Home<a> <!-- simulating that the user is on this page -->
<a href="about.php"<?php echo is_current('about.php'); ?>>About me</a>
<a href="contact.php"<?php echo is_current('contact.php'); ?>>Contact me!</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the requested url, you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` for that and your function should look like this

```
function underlinePage($pageYouWant) {
  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/".$pageYouWant)) {
    return 'underline';
  }
}
```

and you call the function like this

```
<div class="navigation>
  <a href="index.php" class="<?= underlinePage('index.php'); ?>">Home<a>
  <a href="about.php" class="<?= underlinePage('about.php'); ?>">About me</a>
  <a href="contact.php" class="<?= underlinePage('contact.php'); ?>">Contact me!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: If you'r going to use request uri, you don't have to define it in every link.  Move it to the function since it will be the same for every link and that way you will only have to call it once.

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 Edit: I'll change it

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution:

```
<?php
    function underline($page) {
        return (basename(__FILE__) === $page) ? 'class="underline"' : '';
    }
       ?>

<div class="navigation">
    <a href="index.php" <?php echo underline('index.php') ?>>Home<a>
    <a href="about.php" <?php echo underline('about.php') ?>>About me</a>
    <a href="contact.php" <?php echo underline('contact.php') ?>>Contact me!</a>
</div>
```